# how to change the color of links ONLY in fieldsets?

Tags: html, css, colors, fieldset

The problem is that the default colors dont go well with my background...
Can someone please tell me how to change the link colors at the bottom of the page to the orange color
http://cisweb.bristolcc.edu/~jcharron17/week8-javascript.html

but also keep the regular colors inside the fieldset?
http://cisweb.bristolcc.edu/~jcharron17/

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the below line

```
<a href="index.html">Return to the Index</a>
```

inside a div in the below way

```
<div id="footer">
<a href="index.html">Return to the Index</a>
</div>
```

And then inside your head tags, write the below css

```
<style type="text/css">
    #footer a {
        color: #F16F01;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Better yet, use the html5 `<footer>` tag instead of `<div id="footer">`... also, you're going to want to specify for LoVe HAte... more to the point, OP, please go out and read up on some CSS basics. A quick explanation of what Ab's code is saying is "inside an object with an ID of 'footer', find all 'a' tags and make them this color" ... and while that will suffice to some degree, you'll notice that in some cases, the color will revert after you've hovered or clicked on the links, which is why you use LoVe HAte to specify colors in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you don't have any specification of your A tags, and you have no way of indicating that the tags down in the footer of your page need to be handled differently from the default.

As Abhishek's example pointed out, you need to wrap those links in something that gives them context. He chose `<div id="footer">`, which is fine, and HTML4+ valid.

I would probably go for the HTML5 specification, myself:

```
<footer>
    <a href="index.html">Return to the Index</a>
</footer>
```

Also, you need to beware of the :link, :visited, :hover, and :active states that all links have by default. This is why normally, to make sure that the color you want stays that color for all states, you specify your link CSS like this:

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    /* your specs here */
}
```

In the case above, you would do:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #footer a, #footer a:link, #footer a:visited, #footer a:hover, #footer a:active {
        color: #F16F01;
    }
</style>
```

just to cover all your bases.

Answer (score 1):

put this code in your website source code at the end..
give your link at place of #
you will get orange color of that text

```
<a href="#"><font color="#F16F01">Return to the Index</font></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `class` to tag `a` like this:

```
<a href="index.html" class="orange">Return to the Index</a>
```

and CSS rules:

```
.orange { color: #F16F01; }
.orange:hover { color: #FF9900; }
```

Or you can use new colors for all links just write next CSS rules:

```
a { color: #F16F01; }
a:hover { color: #FF9900; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fieldset a{
   color: pink;
}
```

Hope will help you